# How to run a script on home page only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't think this is a very basic question, but I need some help or if you can guide me to a resource I'd appreciate it.   I have a script that I would like to run only when the visitor comes for the first time.

```
<script>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $(".posts").hide();
    $("#header").hide();
    $("#body").hide();
    $("#footer").hide();
    $("#intro").click(function(){
    $(".posts").show(3000);
    $("#header").show(3000);
    $("#body").fadeIn(3000);
    $("#footer").show(3000);
    $("#intro").hide();
    $("p").hide();
});
```

});

How do I go about this?  The visitor enters my site and everything is hidden, then they press a button and it shows everything in a cool way.  I do not want to run this script again after visitor returns back to home page from some other page on the website.  Any ideas on how this can be done?  I am using javascript with jquery.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Thank you Emeeus and Chiran K. for helping me.  This is the code and it works fine.  For first time visitor, we enter if-block, first time visitor clicks button and enters site.  When visitor goes back to home page, it goes to else block, and hides what I want.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem("firstTime")){ 
        $(".posts").hide();
        $("#header").hide();
        $("#body").hide();
        $("#footer").hide();
        $("#start").click(function(){$(".posts").show(3000); $("#header").show(3000); $("#body").fadeIn(3000); $("#footer").show(3000);$("#start").hide(); $("p").hide(); });
        localStorage.setItem("firstTime","true");
    } else {
        $("#start").hide();
        $("p").hide();
    }
```

});

Comment: Set a cookie or store a flag in localStorage. Check if it exists before running your code

Comment: I'd like to clarify: a visitor comes to your website, clicks the button to display everything, and they go away from your website. If they come back, they should not have to click any buttons, and everything is already shown?

Comment: Hi JonLim, that's not what I'm looking for, but a solution to that or information on that may even be helpful.  If they come back after going away, I want them to click button again.  I just don't want them to have to press button again when they go back to home page from some other page on the site.

Comment: "if they come back after going away" specifically means if they exit or completely close the web site.  Hope it's clear enough.  I guess I'll have to look into what charlietfl said for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work

```
if(!localStorage.getItem("firstTime")){
    //code executed first time
    localStorage.setItem("firstTime","true");
}else{
    //code executed 2th 3th etc.
}
```

That could be executed after some event, like `click` or `onload`. Keep in mind that you could store whatever you want with localStorage.

Comment: Hello, I used your code and it doesn't seem to work.  Please see my edit, did I make some careless error?

Comment: Thank you, this is the correct answer, I'm just too new with localStorage and was coding it without the else statement.

Comment: @Fortunata If I understand well, I think you need to put that code in the else part.

Comment: Yes, I updated my post with the code and it works.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this depending on your exact requirement.

If you want to handle it once per session, then you can have a session variable and handle it.

If you want to handle it once per user agent, then you can use either local storage or cookies to handle it.

refer [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-sessionstorage-localstorage-and-Cookies) for more info.